# Multilanguage in a HTML webpage

Tags: javascript, android, html, web

I am realtivly new to web programming and I am looking for something similar as res/values/strings.xml in android, but for a webpage. Does something like this exist (a link to a book describing this solution)? 
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried asking google.com for help?

Comment: Yes, I have searched it on google for the last 3 hours. I only found a PHP example >> http://www.bitrepository.com/php-how-to-add-multi-language-support-to-a-website.html and nothing else.

Comment: I can't see why this question has been put on hold. Really helpful attitude and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to read about knockout.js, I think it's useful framework in your case.

Comment: I'm not sure that knockout can help me in this matter. From what I know, it is designed to bind the View with the Model and I have used it until now only for this.

Comment: Why not?
You can write something like this in your html page:`<span data-bind="text: fullName"> </span>`. Your server can generate dictionary `{fullName: "some text"}` which will fit user's language using your strings.xml

Comment: It seems like a great solution. I will give it a try. Thanks